# Does oral sex during the day in Ramadan invalidate the fast?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, sex

How about, if the wife who is not fasting gives oral sex to the husband who is fasting without ejaculation taking place? Is it permitted?

Answer (score 5):

Scholars say that as long as neither of the husband or wife had ejaculation due to sexual arousal their fast is valid (assuming even the wife was fasting). (See [this](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/164407) or [this](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/138686) fatwa in Arabic or [this](https://islamqa.info/en/49752) in English) Note that the fast of any of them would only become invalid once a ejaculation takes place. And in your case only the fast of the husband could become invalid, as the wife isn't fasting.

On the other hand oral sex is considered by some scholars as an act of bad taste and is allowed under the condition that wife accepts this and is sure not so swallow any impurity. (See [this](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/139096) fatwa in Arabic)
**Note** that fiqh scholars defined fast as the abstention of the desires of the haunch and stomach one should really not play with fire in Ramadan and keep away from it until one is allowed to do what ever one wants (during the nights) (as sassir quoted in his comment).

See also this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/66803) on intimacy while fasting in Ramadan.
Here a quote:

> The view that masturbation or intimacy with one's wife to the point of ejaculation are among the things that invalidate the fast is the view of the majority of scholars, including the four imams, Abu Haneefah, Maalik, al-Shaafa’i and Ahmad. They quoted as evidence the fact that it is satisfaction of desire, and that is forbidden to the person who is fasting, because Allaah says, according to the hadeeth qudsi about the fasting person: “He gives up his food, his drink and his desire for My sake.” Narrated by [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/4)

See also these fatwas [on intimacy with the wife](https://islamqa.info/en/71213) in Ramadan and on [exchanging affectionate words](https://islamqa.info/en/65698) while fasting.

And Allah knows best!

Comment: I would add that fast is defined as the abstention of the desires of the haunch and stomach one should really not play with fire in Ramadan and keep away from it until one is allowed to do what ever one wants (during the nights).

Answer (score 0):

Oral is still intercourse and a form of sex, therefor to give or recieve oral during fasting hours will invalidate the fast regardless of ejaculation or not.

Comment: Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].