# Are things like lube and food allowed to be used during maritial relations?

Tags: sex, husband-wife

To "spice"  up their sex life, can these be used between a married couple? Is it islamically permissible?

Comment: Related to: [How can adventurous Muslim spouses spice up their sex life?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36335/17163)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you use halal product, the answer is "YES they are allowed". Because there are no authentic hadiths or verses in Quran which prohibits the use of addons and utilities such as food or halal lubes during sex.